# How is ordering mantained in Kafka Streams Application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am writing a kafka stream application which will do stateless transformation on several topics and push data to a different topic. The topology will be 1:1 i.e. multiple input -> output topic pairs with a one to one mapping for each pair.

If I do scale this out and have several instances of this app, which means that there will be multiple consumers and producers for the same topic pair across instances, how will kafka streams maintain ordering of the data? (or does it not maintain ordering?)

Technically I do need to maintain ordering of the data since these are log events, and I need them to be properly ordered instead of out of order in the eventual data lake.

Comment: How many partitions do topics have? You cannot guarantee any ordering with more than one partition or across multiple topics

Comment: Can we guarantee ordering within a partition... multiple producers and one partition per producer. I dont need ordering across all the producers, but for messages from a single producer when consumed and transformed and produced again in kafka stream should retain ordering @OneCricketeer

Comment: That should be fine if you set `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1`